# Как заполнить pdf-документ из данных формы?

Tags: python, pdf, поиск-библиотек, doc

Есть форма на сайте. Пользователь заполняет её. Эти данные, из формы, вносятся в pdf файл в определенные места. Например, есть сертификат, готовый, в котором поле с ФИО пустое, пользователь вводит свое ФИО в input на сайте, и это ФИО попадает на сертификат в нужное место.
Как взаимодействовать с pdf форматом с помощью, Python, или есть ли какое нибудь API для редактирования PDF или doc форматов?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PyPDF2 подойдёт, но нужно подобрать межсимвольный интервал и шрифты